# How to separate concerns between a players cash and its manipulation?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, theory, separation-of-concerns

In a very small game I am writing a `player` has some cash (which is just an `Int`), but I don't want to directly manipulate the cash in the `player` class; I feel the player class shouldn't care about cash manipulation.

As such, I move all cash manipulation into another class.

Here's where I get all confused. I am reading up on VIPER and other patterns where "walled gardens" mean that a class will usually not know about its parent or have direct access to another object.

So, when it comes to this, I'm not sure if I'm meant to seperate the concern between a player's cash and the ability to credit/debit cash into a player's wallet, or not.

In my cash handler I need to do some error checking, `throw` errors, and stuff; for now this is not important to my question; hence I've removed these to focus on the main thrust of my question.

I am using Swift Playgrounds to play around with 2 main ideas I have about how to tackle this small issue.

```
// : Idea #1 -- Use static functions

class Player {
    var cash: Int = 0
}
let p = Player.init()


struct Wallet{
    static func credit(account: Player, amount: Int) {
        // (#TODO) the final one will do some checks, throw an error
        var balance: Int = account.cash
        balance += amount
        account.cash = balance
    }
    static func debit(account: Player, amount: Int)  {
        // (#TODO) the final one will do some checks, throw an error
        var balance: Int = account.cash
        balance -= amount
        account.cash = balance
    }
}
Wallet.credit(account: p, amount: 125)
Wallet.debit(account: p, amount: 25)
print (p.cash)
```

Okay, in this one I use static functions; but the `Wallet` struct has direct access to the player.  I feel this is wrong.

My second attempt:

```
class Player {
    var account: Account = Account()

    var cash: Int {
        return account.balance
    }

    init(cash: Int) {
        self.account = Account(openingBalance: cash)
    }
}

var p = Player.init(cash: 50)

class Account {
    public private(set) var balance: Int = 0

    init(openingBalance: Int = 0) {
        self.balance = openingBalance
    }

    func credit(amount: Int) -> Int {
        balance += amount
        return self.balance
    }

    func deposit(amount: Int) -> Int {
        balance -= amount
        return self.balance
    }
}

p.account.credit(amount: 100)
print (p.cash)
```

This one feels cleaner, but now the `Player` object has direct access to the `Account`?

---

Edit: I have a third attempt.  I saw something called a `proxy design pattern`, sorry if I'm not familar with the pattern; as I understand it, you could have something in between the player and the bank account acting as a proxy to decide whether or not a player can credit or debit their account.

Sadly, this experiment doesn't quite work; I have now a seemingly endless loop of do-catch statements; I'm not sure how I kick it back to the main program.

```
// : Third attempt -- I think this follows a Proxy pattern

public enum CashError: Error, Equatable {
    case mustBePositive
    case notEnoughFunds
    case cannotPerformTransaction
    case amountWouldBeNegative
}

class Bank {
    var balance: Int = 0

    enum TransactionType: Int {
        case credit = 0
        case debit
    }

    func performTransaction(transactionType: TransactionType, amount: Int) {
        switch transactionType {
        case .credit:
            self.credit(amount: amount)
        case .debit:
            self.debit(amount: amount)
        }
    }

    private func credit(amount: Int = 0) {
        print ("didCredit: \(amount)")
        self.balance += amount
    }

    private func debit(amount: Int = 0) {
        print ("didDebit: \(amount)")
        self.balance -= amount
    }
}

class Customer {
    private(set) var accountProxy: AccountProxy?

    var cash: Int {
        guard let proxy: AccountProxy = accountProxy else {
            return 0
        }
        return proxy.balance
    }

    init(cash: Int = 0) {
        print ("Create player with $\(cash)")

        self.accountProxy = AccountProxy.init(customer: self)

        guard let proxy = self.accountProxy else {
            return
        }

        do {
            let _ = try proxy.handle(transactionType: .credit, amount: cash)
        } catch {
            print (error)
        }
    }
}

class AccountProxy {
    private var bank: Bank = Bank()
    private var customer: Customer
    public var balance: Int {
        return self.bank.balance
    }

    init(customer: Customer) {
        self.customer = customer
    }

    func handle(transactionType: Bank.TransactionType, amount: Int = 0) throws -> Bool {
        print ("Attempting \(transactionType) of $\(amount)")

        do {
            if let _ = try canPerformTransaction(transactionType: transactionType, amount: amount) {
                print ("proxy: says you can \(transactionType): $\(amount)")
                self.bank.performTransaction(transactionType: transactionType, amount: amount)
                return true
            }
            else {
                print ("proxy: error - Cannot perform transction")
                throw CashError.cannotPerformTransaction
            }
        } catch {
            throw (error)
        }
    }

    // (Private) functions

    private func canPerformTransaction(transactionType: Bank.TransactionType, amount: Int ) throws -> Bool? {
        switch transactionType {
        case .credit:
            do {
                guard let result = try canCredit(amount: amount) else {
                    return false
                }
                return result
            } catch {
                throw error
            }

        case .debit:
            do {
                guard let result = try canDebit(amount: amount) else {
                    return false
                }
                return result
            } catch {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }

    private func canCredit(amount: Int) throws -> Bool? {
        guard amount >= 0 else {
            throw CashError.mustBePositive
        }
        return true
    }

    private func canDebit(amount: Int) throws -> Bool? {
        // amount must be > 0
        guard amount > 0 else {
           throw CashError.mustBePositive
       }
        // balance must be >= amount
       guard balance >= amount else {
           throw CashError.notEnoughFunds
       }
        // the remaining sum must be >= 0
       let sum = balance
       guard ((sum - amount) >= 0) else {
           throw CashError.amountWouldBeNegative
       }
        return true
    }
}


let bob = Customer.init(cash: 100)
print ("Bob has $\(bob.cash)")
do {
    let _ = try bob.accountProxy?.handle(transactionType: .credit, amount: 125)
} catch {
    print (error)
}
print ("Bob has $\(bob.cash)")
do {
    let _ = try bob.accountProxy?.handle(transactionType: .debit, amount: 25)
} catch {
    print (error)
}
print ("Bob has $\(bob.cash)")

// (Logged Output):
// Create player with $100
// Attempting credit of $100
// proxy: says you can credit: $100
// didCredit: 100
// Bob has $100
// Attempting credit of $125
// proxy: says you can credit: $125
// didCredit: 125
// Bob has $225
// Attempting debit of $25
// proxy: says you can debit: $25
// didDebit: 25
// Bob has $200
```

Thus my query is based on the "walled gardens" concept?  Should the player class have knowledge of its account?

I apologize if this seems obvious, I find it very frustrating/confusing.

I appreciate any feedback/assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course with such a small example, separating concerns is probably not very useful, but I'll go with it...

```swift
class Player {
    let wallet: Wallet
    // no reference to cash here.
}

class Wallet {
    private var cash: Int
    // methods manipulating cash go here.
}
```

Now a player doesn't need to have any code revolving around manipulating the `cash` variable, but it means that the Player will have to expose its Wallet so that others can put cash in and take it out. This separates the concerns but breaks containment. The Player object can no longer control who or what takes cash out of its wallet and, given the real world examples of these things, that sounds like a rather bad idea.

You could make Wallet private in Player, but doing so makes the Wallet superfluous. Unless you don't trust the Player to ensure that its `cash` doesn't go negative of course.

The use-cases will dictate the likely appropriate relationships. My favorite example is regarding a Car and its Engine. For the "startCar" use case, the obvious relationship is containment `[Car]<>-->[Engine]`. The driver doesn't care a whit about the internals of an Engine when it wants to start the car. However, for the "change oil" use case, the best relationship is an association `[Car]--->[Engine]` because the Mechanic will want to have direct access to the engine without having to lift the Engine out of the car and replace it every time he needs to make a change.

I hope this rambling helps...

Comment: I wish to thank you -- I appreciate the feedback.  Yes, I know the example is very bare bones and doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things.  I'm just trying to understand some design patterns and clarify this concept of seperating concerns.   I was reading up on a proxy pattern, which looks good -- but ends up in a chain of do-catch because the result might be an error

Comment: Hi there.  I did some amends: 
```class Player {
    let wallet: Wallet = Wallet()
    var cash: Int {
        self.wallet.cash
    }
}

class Wallet {
    private (set) var cash: Int = 0
    // methods manipulating cash go here.

    func credit(_ amount: Int) {
        self.cash += amount
    }
}

let bob = Player()
bob.wallet.credit(100)
let alex = Player()
alex.wallet.credit(150)
let sarah = Player()
sarah.wallet.credit(275)

print (bob.cash)
print (alex.cash)
print (sarah.cash)```

Comment: I think your right, I just have a tendancy to try to overcomplicate stuff

Comment: Here's something to think about... Every class should have some invariant(s) that it's trying to maintain. The obvious invariant in this case is `cash >= 0`, but maybe you can think of others. Now which class is in charge of maintaining that invariant? No other class should ever have to worry about that.

Comment: I think I understand.  In the game, players can add cards to their "hand" and there are other things happen which affects a player class, I just wanted to move these to other places and have seperation between them -- but I think what I've learnt is that maybe its just better to get it done, and not worry so much on getting it right first time